# Inexplicable behaviour while inserting form data to mongodb using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/shopper');

    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    //give constriants of schema and columns
    var productSchema =Schema({

        product_Name : String ,
        product_Description :String ,
        product_price : Number ,
        product_logo :String   

    });
    //create model of the schema 
     var product = mongoose.model('product',productSchema)

module.exports = router.post('/AddProduct',function(req,resp){

    console.log(req.body);

//create schema

 var newproduct = new product({

    product_Name : req.body.product_Name ,
    product_Description : req.body.product_Description ,
    product_price : req.body.product_price,
    product_logo : req.body.product_logo 
 });
console.log(newproduct);
newproduct.save(function(err){
    if(err) console.log("insertion failed");
});
    resp.status(200).redirect('./add-Product-form/');


});
```

console.log(req.body);

```
{ product_Name: 's',
  product_description: 'ydtdh',
  product_price: '232',
  product_logo: 'error.png' }
```

console.log(newproduct)

```
{ _id: 5a6ffc303df3d62e0451dd12,
  product_Name: 's',
  product_price: 232,
  product_logo: 'error.png' }
```

why is this anomaly happening when I have set everything right or am I missing something.When document is inserted to mongodb a column is missing

Answer (score 1):

`req.body` returns:

```
{ product_Name: 's',
  product_description: 'ydtdh',
  product_price: '232',
  product_logo: 'error.png' }
```

The field `product_description` is supposed to be `product_Description`. 
 
It's simply a matter of the Schema being *case-sensitive*

Comment: I think this answer is correct, but you need to make it explicit : case-sensitivity matters.

Answer (score 0):

In your form change the `textarea` or `input` element with the name of `product_description` to `product_Description` (notice the capital `D` in Description), Then directly do:

```
var newproduct = new product(req.body);
newproduct.save(function(err) { ...  });
```

OR use create method:

```
Product.create(req.body, function (err, newProduct) { ... });
```